# Encoding issue while fetching with Java HTTP Request

Tags: java, rest, http

I am trying to hit a URL with a Java HTTP request. I have tried with both encodings and without encoding methods for it. It failed with both approaches.

URL: > [https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q={$and:[{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$gte](https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q=%7B$and:%5B%7BcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:%7B$gte): '2023-04-01'}},{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$lte: '2023-06-04'}},{customerSigned_srq:{ $exists: false }},{renewalType_srq:{ $eq: "Amendment" }},{subType_srq:{ $eq: "Proactive" }}]}&fields=quoteNumber_srq,customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq

Here is my source code:

```
URL url = new URI(uri).toURL();
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
var apiUsername = "***";
var apiPassword = "***";
conn.setRequestProperty(HEADERS_AUTHORIZATION, generateBasicAuthInHeaders(apiUsername, apiPassword));
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();
```

Error I am getting without encoding:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 98

If I encode only the query part:

URL will be like:

> [https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q=%7B%24and%3A%5B%7BcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A%7B%24gte%3A+%272023-04-01%27%7D%7D%2C%7BcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A%7B%24lte%3A+%272023-06-04%27%7D%7D%2C%7BcustomerSigned_srq%3A%7B+%24exists%3A+false+%7D%7D%2C%7BrenewalType_srq%3A%7B+%24eq%3A+%22Amendment%22+%7D%7D%2C%7BsubType_srq%3A%7B+%24eq%3A+%22Proactive%22+%7D%7D%5D%7D%26fields%3DquoteNumber_srq%2CcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq`](https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q=%7B%24and%3A%5B%7BcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A%7B%24gte%3A+%272023-04-01%27%7D%7D%2C%7BcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A%7B%24lte%3A+%272023-06-04%27%7D%7D%2C%7BcustomerSigned_srq%3A%7B+%24exists%3A+false+%7D%7D%2C%7BrenewalType_srq%3A%7B+%24eq%3A+%22Amendment%22+%7D%7D%2C%7BsubType_srq%3A%7B+%24eq%3A+%22Proactive%22+%7D%7D%5D%7D%26fields%3DquoteNumber_srq%2CcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%60)

and I am getting the response:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:

I have tried using Jersey client for URL building:

```
URI url = UriBuilder.fromPath("https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction")
        .queryParam("q", "{$and:[{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$gte: '2023-04-01'}},{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$lte: '2023-06-04'}},{customerSigned_srq:{ $exists: false }},{renewalType_srq:{ $eq: \"Amendment\" }},{subType_srq:{ $eq: \"Proactive\" }}]}&fields=quoteNumber_srq,customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq")
        .build();
```

I didn't get success either. Any help would be great.

Comment: The first version is clearly incorrect.  Characters such as `[`, `]` and `:` in the query part must be encoded. In the second version, the problem is mostly something to do with the URL path being unknown to the server or the query being invalid.  Check the response body for error messages and the server access and error logs.  (We have no knowledge of the server you are trying to use or its request syntax.)

Comment: I could see postman sending encoded url like this:

'https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q={%24and%3A[{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A{%24gte%3A%20%272023-04-13%27}}%2C{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq%3A{%24lte%3A%20%272023-07-14%27}}%2C{customerSigned_srq%3A{%20%24exists%3A%20false%20}}%2C{renewalType_srq%3A{%20%24eq%3A%20%27Amendment%27}}%2C{subType_srq%3A{%20%24eq%3A%20%27Proactive%27}}]}&fields=quoteNumber_srq%2CcustomerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq'


I dont know what encoding its using, but its getting proper result

Comment: Put the details into the question.  They are unreadable in the comments.  (Look at it!!)

Comment: @StephenC 
{"type":"HTTP://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Parameter q is invalid.\nUnexpected character ('&' (code 38)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (String)\"{$and:[{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$gte: '2023-04-01'}},{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$lte: '2023-06-04'}},{customerSigned_srq:{ $exists: false }},{renewalType_srq:{ $eq: \"Amendment\" }},{subType_srq:{ $eq: \"Proactive\" }}]}&fields=quoteNumber_srq,customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq\"; line: 1, column: 240]"}

Comment: And it is completely unreadable.  This is a >you< problem!   Use the [Edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76934595/edit).

Comment: By the way ... you seem to be setting a `Content-Type` header in your `GET` request.  That has no effect since your request has no body.  The header is redundant.

Comment: @StephenC I have encoded the part still '&' and sent it. Its working. All I need to find is how to append parameters with & symbol. coz I am getting the error:

Unexpected character ('&' (code 38)):

Comment: I'm not answering any further until you fix the question.  This is the 3rd and final time I will say this.  All relevant information should be 1) in the question (not the comments) and 2) readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution to this. I am posting here, so it may help whomever face this:

Solution: Instead of sending complete encoded URL, I sent it partially encoded like below:

```
String encodedUrl = `"https://host.com/rest/v14/commerceDocumentsSimplifiedRenewalsTransaction?q=" +  URLEncoder.encode("{$and:[{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$gte: '2023-04-01'}},{customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq:{$lte: '2023-06-04'}},{customerSigned_srq:{ $exists: false }},{renewalType_srq:{ $eq: \"Amendment\" }},{subType_srq:{ $eq: \"Proactive\" }}]}", StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "&fields="+ URLEncoder.encode("quoteNumber_srq,customerSignatureRequestSentOn_srq", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
```

and it worked...

If anyone has a better approach, please share.

Thanks.